# detailview controller value not showing

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios6

While using the `DetailViewController` the value is not passing from the `UITabelViewController`, is it any wrong with the code?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

detailedvu *dvController = [[detailedvu alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailedvu" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
if (0 == indexPath.row)
{
    NSLog(@"0");
    dvController.lb1.text = @"Make";
}
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
}
```

Please help me to sort out.

Comment: Your code is not very descriptive about what is happening.
BTW you should name the classes with uppercase :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dvcontroller` is instantiated correctly.The problem here is that the `lbl` is a label from the nib(i think).So when pushed to the viewcontroller a new instance is created so the setting here does not make any sense.

Pass it in a data holder such as NSString and load the label in the `viewdidLoad` of the `detailedvu`

One suggestion : Please try to follow the naming conventions for better readability

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

You can achive this using this.

Create a string variable property in detailedvu.h file :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * str;
```

And in detailedvu.m file add this :

```
@synthesize str;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (str.length!=0) {
        NSLog(@"hi%@",str);
        lb1.text=str;
    }
}
```

And in your table vc .m file put this code :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

detailedvu *dvController = [[detailedvu alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailedvu" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
if (0 == indexPath.row)
{
    NSLog(@"0");
    dvController.str = @"Make";
}
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
}
```